# Transcribing Feuz

Tags: names, transcription

I was wondering how you would transcribe Feuz into Japanese.

The word is pronounced like "Foyts". I am thinking it would be フォイツ?

Comment: http://www.alpineracenet.com/top-racers/%E3%83%99%E3%82%A2%E3%83%88-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%84-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9/

Answer (score 3):

If this name is of  German origin, then yes, *eu* is usually transliterated as オイ. フォイツ sounds reasonable to me (well, I only have limited knowledge of German).

[東外大言語モジュール ドイツ語 発音 実践編 > 5 EuropaとEuro](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/de/pmod/practical/01-05-01.php)

But Feuz may have other readings in other European languages. [See this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/21180/5010).